# Dockerizing Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, delayed-job

We are currently working on *Dockerizing* our Ruby on Rails application, which also includes Delayed Job. A question buzzing within our development team is whether and/or how to Dockerize the Delayed Job component separately from the application.

This would allow Delayed Job to start up new containers when necessary for high traffic within the jobs queue. In addition, since Delayed Job actually starts up the Rails application each time when first booting up, we thought the following benefits would follow:

1. The Delayed Job container might start up quicker
2. Application code would start up regardless of the Delayed Job container startup time

Comment: Really, the worker needs to have the rails stack just like the application container does, with the exception that it's command would be the delayed job daemon instead of the rails server

Comment: @DVG Is there any benefit to running it in a separate container then? There of course is the added ideology of a single process per container, but also we can scale up the delayed job process regardless of the actual application state.

Comment: Sure, they can still be scaled independently of the application, but it still needs to boot the app to do its job

Answer (score 2):

So I know a guy responsible for a rails app that uses delayed jobs.  When it came time to dockerize said app, it got a container for each.  Both containers are using the same codebase but one runs the frontend and one the jobs.  It's not devops microservice-eriffic but it works.

Outside of the logical separation between the two, docker containers are supposed to only have a single process running inside.  Could've hacked it together but it seemed wrong to break a docker fundamental out of the gate.